# Does Event Viewer just allows you to view the logs of the user profile that is logged into the computer?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, event-log, event-viewer, events

Does Event Viewer just allows you to view the logs of the user profile that is logged into the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Event viewer shows events from the whole system and is not user-specific

Comment: So how would I be able to differentiate between the different problems that users have with the system if a few people have logged into the machine at different times of the day. Does it come up on the log with what user the problem was with?

Comment: No, you'll have to separately work out which user was logged on at which time. Event viewer can have log on/off events as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-logon-events